# PHP undocumented automatically decode content-type:application/json to $_REQUEST

Tags: php, json, content-type, phalcon

**Is there really an undocumented feature in PHP to decode JSON POST body to $_REQUEST?**

Not the same as [PHP is automatically decoding JSON data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25553249/php-is-automatically-decoding-json-data)

I am creating an API in PHP to receive parameters in FormData and JSON.  When I test in POSTMAN, it appears that PHP automatically decodes POST body with `content-type:application/json` to `$_REQUEST`.

I have been testing it whole afternoon and can't figure out how it is possible.

This is the post request:

```
curl -X POST \
  http://xxxxx.com/api/user/profile/update \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -d '{
    "id" : 174,
    "email" : "reed@xxxxx.com",
    "lang": "en_US",
}'
```

This is what I got in PHP

```
var_dump($_REQUEST)

//output
  'id' => int 174
  'email' => string 'reed@xxxxx.com' (length=19)
  'lang' => string 'en_US' (length=5)
```

Am I seeing **delusion**??

If I change POST content-type to anything which is not **`application/json`**, the automatic decoding does not happen.

I am using PHP5.6 + Phalcon 3.1.  Both not mentioning anything about automatically decoding JSON.

Here is my `composer.json`, I don't think any of these packages will do such a thing.

```
"require": {
    "twilio/sdk" : "4.*",
    "crossjoin/browscap": "~2.0",
    "mixpanel/mixpanel-php" : "2.*",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.2",
    "geoip2/geoip2": "~2.0",
    "overtrue/wechat": "~3.1",
    "mongodb/mongodb": "^1.0.0",
    "symfony/var-dumper": "^3.1",
    "maxmind-db/reader": "~1.0",
    "pda/pheanstalk": "^3.1",
    "nesbot/carbon": "^1.21",
    "sendgrid/sendgrid": "~5.1",
    "ramsey/uuid": "^3.5",
    "phpmyadmin/motranslator": "^3.0"
}
```

Tried my best to search on google. Can someone point me to a document with some explanation?

Comment: Are you sure that made by php? May be phalcon or your dependencies makes this.

Comment: @kodmanyagha I am sure phalcon has no such feature.  But don't know other possibilities.  I tested the application in a barebone controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out. It is **PECL :: Package :: json_post**

https://pecl.php.net/package/json_post

> This extension provides a PHP content type handler for
>   "application/json" and  "text/json" to PHP's form data parser. If the
>   `Content-Type` of an incoming  request is `text/json`, the JSON
>   contents of the request body will by parsed  into `$_POST`.

I use remi repo to install PHP on centos. It just comes with my installation of PHP 5.6